# AS3 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String

Tags: actionscript-3

I am getting error: "1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String."

When attempting to run:

```
var cam_array: Array = Camera.names;
for (var ci:Number=0; ci < cam_array.length; ci++){
    trace(Camera.getCamera(ci).name);
}
```

yet when I run:

```
var mic_array: Array = Microphone.names;
for (var mi:Number=0; mi < mic_array.length; mi++){
    trace(Microphone.getMicrophone(mi).name);
}
```

there is no issue.
The only change is from Microphone to Camera, so what gives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the parameter in getCamera is probably a String. Unrelated: why are you using number in for loops? use int.

Comment: Unrelated reason: This is my first time using AS3, or ActionScript for that matter, and it's been a few years since my last go at scripting.

Comment: a for loop is typically used with an int not a Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Camera`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html) function [`getCamera()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera()) accepts an optional parameter of `name`:

> `name:String` (default = null) — Specifies which camera to get, as
>   determined from the array returned by the names property. For most
>   applications, get the default camera by omitting this parameter. To
>   specify a value for this parameter, use the string representation of
>   the zero-based index position within the Camera.names array. For
>   example, to specify the third camera in the array, use
>   Camera.getCamera("2").

If you do not want the default parameter, cast the index position to a string:

```
var cam_array:Array = Camera.names;
for (var ci:uint = 0; ci < cam_array.length; ci++){
    trace(Camera.getCamera(ci.toString()).name);
}
```

Another method to loop camera names would be:

```
var cam_array:Array = Camera.names;
for each (var camera:String in cam_array) {
    trace(camera);
}
```

On the other hand, [`Microphone`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html) function [`getMicrophone()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#getMicrophone()) accepts an optional parameter of index:

> `index:int` (default = -1) — The index value of the microphone.